# if all three condition is exactly met then "ok"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

If 1) C1>0 and 2) D1<0 and 3) E1>0 is the condition. now my query is that if first two conditions (i.e.C1>0 and D1<0) is exactly met but third condition (i.e. E1>0) is not met, then there should be "Not Ok", otherewise there should be blank.

It is compulsory that first two condition to exactly met and then if third condition is not met, then there should be "not ok" otherwise there should be blank.

Hope you might properly understand what I want.

and hopefully, I expect, someone will gladden me solving my query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
= IF(AND(C1>0,D1<0),IF(E1>0,"OK","NOT OK"),"")
```

If both of the first two conditions are met, and third condtion is met, then `OK`.

If both of the first two conditions are met, and third condition is not met, then `NOT OK`.

If either of the first two conditions are not met, then blank.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like:

```
=IF(AND(C1 > 0,D1 < 0,E1 > 0), "OK", "NOT OK")
```

The combination of the `IF` and `AND` functions are what allows this to work. We check that all 3 conditions have been met and return OK or NOT OK based on that.

Comment: Sir please see I have modified my query to make you more understand about it.